# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region across the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region across the $y$-axis bounded by the graphs of the equations: $x=y^2, x=20y-y^2$, the line $x=102$.

I set up an integral from $0$ to $10$ using the equation $\sqrt{x}$ but for the other equation I don't know how to make it usable. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the second parabola into standard form:

$x - 100 = -(y-10)^2$ which has a vertex at $(100, 10)$ and opens to the left. By coincidence, this is also a point on both parabolas. The line $x = 102$ does not come into play (or else there is no region bounded by all three boundaries together).

[image: region bounded by the two parabolas]

Because of the form of the two parabolas, it is easier to integrate along the $y-$axis, in which case the washer or disc method is being used. Each disc is an annulus with inner radius $r_i = y^2$, outer radius $r_o = 20y-y^2$, and thickness $dy$. So for the element of volume

$$\mathrm{d}V = \pi(r_o^2 - r_i^2) dy = \pi [(20y - y^2)^2 - (y^2)^2] \, \mathrm{d}y = \pi (400 y^2 -40y) \, \mathrm{d}y$$

So

$$V = \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{10}{\pi (400 y^2 -40y) \,  \mathrm{d}y}$$

which is straight-forward.